# Why ReadLine().ToUpper() and not ToUpper(ReadLine())?

Tags: c#, string

Beginner question ahead.

If I want to convert input string (from console) to uppercase the syntax is the following one:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

Since "ToUpper()" is a method, I'm confused as to why console input is not its parameter?

```
string text = String.ToUpper(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ToUpper` is declared like this according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-6.0#system-string-toupper):

```
public string ToUpper ();
```

Notice that it has no [`static` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). This means that you should call it on *an instance* of a string, like the value returned by `Console.ReadLine()`, rather than on the class `string`. Also note that it takes no parameters (empty parentheses).

If it were declared like this instead:

```
public static string ToUpper (string s);
```

Then your way of calling it, `string.ToUpper(Console.ReadLine())`. In this case, it is `static`, so you should call it on the `string` class - the class in which it is declared, and it also takes a `string` parameter, which you have passed `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Can you point me to a relevant C# documentation that talks about these different kinds of method calls? As you put it, calling on the instance vs calling on the class.

Comment: @4r73m190r0s I'm not sure if this sort of pattern has a name, but I can give you a link to the documentation for the [`static` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), which is what allows you to call a method on a class. Perhaps that will help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload `ToUpper()` method that reads string as an argument and it is not even static method to use it like `String.ToUpper()`.

There are only [two overload methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-6.0#overloads) that convert a string into upper.

- [`ToUpper()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-6.0#system-string-toupper): Returns a copy of this string converted to uppercase.
- [`ToUpper(CultureInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-6.0#system-string-toupper(system-globalization-cultureinfo)): Returns a copy of this string converted to uppercase, using the casing rules of the specified culture.